# What is the CLI equivalent of "exposing an API" in the Kyma console

Tags: kubernetes, kyma

- `kubectl expose` doesn't work here
- how to do it with CLI
- In Console UI functionality is located in  https://console.kyma.local/home/environments/stage/apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- API exposure to internet is realized through special "API Gateway" component. You can read about its architecture and usage here https://kyma-project.io/docs/latest/components/api-gateway
- Exposure through Console UI https://console.kyma.local/home/environments/stage/apis is realized by actually creating Api CRD
- CLI equivalent is simple `kubectl apply {yaml_file}`. Description of all the fields of Api CRD and an example can be found here https://kyma-project.io/docs/latest/components/api-gateway#custom-resource-custom-resource